# How to access environement variable inside a Gnome-Shell extension

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I want to access environment variable from a Gnome-Shell extension.

Some context: I want to create an extension adding "Xorg" or "Wayland" to the panel, based upon the environment variable `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. I have to do this because I frequently switch (Wine has issues with Wayland), and I don't always remember which type of session is running.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find  how to get environment variables in the source code of the [Argos extension](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos):

```js
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib ;
const rawEnv = GLib.get_environ() ;
```

Also the environment variable are stored as an array of strings and should be parsed, i.e.: split on the first '=' occurrence to separate the key and the value.

**EDIT:** `GLib.getenv('ENV_VAR_NAME')` is more convenient because it avoids parsing the environment variable (thanks to @andyholmes).

Comment: You can also just use `GLib.getenv('XDG_SESSION_TYPE')`.

Comment: @andy.holmes Nice! Added it to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to detect Wayland is to ask the window manager:

```
Meta.is_wayland_compositor()
```

Tested in GS 3.36, 3.38 and 40.

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta3~3.30.2/meta.is_wayland_compositor](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/meta3%7E3.30.2/meta.is_wayland_compositor)

Edit: From extension only, not available from prefs.